# What house did Albus Severus Potter get put into? Was it Gryffindor or Slytherin?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

At the end of the Deathly Hallows Part 2 Albus Potter questions to Harry "What if I am put in Slytherin" So what was he actually sorted into?

Comment: AFAIK, there's zero canon info on that. Probably won't be ever, until Pottermore finishes book 7. Or JKR decides to write the sequels because they'll sell millions of copies too.

Comment: I know its not accepted as a canon question, but seens as we're on the topic "which house do you believe he was put into?" @DVK

Comment: backwards. "What house was he put on" is accepted (just because there's no answer, doesn't make the question invalid). "what house do you believe" is NOT acceptable as that's just pure subjective opinion and speculation.

Comment: Yeah but I'm saying just out of curiousity of what another enthuisiast thinks about it. I will take none of your opinion into knowledgable acceptance I was just trying to find out what u think he was put in purely to make conversation

Comment: @Tgnat - good call!

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, there's zero canon info on that. Probably won't be ever, but we won't know until Pottermore finishes book 7 or JKR writes the sequels (50 push-ups says she will).  Nothing on interviews/Pottermore so far.

Having said that, we can make some informed noting of the possible factors impacting that:

1. While students do get sorted into "foreign" houses from their family (Seriously, Black?), that seems like a RARE exception. So that's a point for Gryffindor.
2. Albus expressed a strong desire to be in G. So that's a point for Gryffindor.
3. His brother is in Gryffindor. A wash (Patil sisters were in different houses). But may reinforce #2.
4. He seems like a trusting kid. Not devious/manipulative. So Slytherin is less likely. He's also recless and dangerous together with his brother ("... when I want the house demolished"). That's Gryffindor all over him. He believes anything anyone tells him (at least his brother), so probably not Ravenclaw material - not to mention his genetics doesn't point to Ravenclaw either.

Comment: Also, he felt some fear of being in Slytherin, no matter what Harry told him his choice was not Slytherin.

Comment: On the Other Hand the kid is named A.S.P., which is of course a snake...

Answer (score 0):

He wanted to choose Gryffindor, so that's most likely, which is all we really have to go on.

Comment: Can the sorting hat read the mind of the student he is placing into a house or if you want him to take your choice into account do you have to verbally tell him which one you want to be in?

Comment: I don't have the books with me here, but go find Harry's sorting in Philosopher's Stone, I'm pretty sure it says he *thinks* "not Slytherin" at the hat, as opposed to saying it aloud.

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed with an audiobook, Harry definitely *thinks* to the hat, and not speaks, so the answer is yes :)

Comment: In very end Harry says Albus *The Shorting Hat takes your choice into account*.